# Why doesn't text-align: center work in my table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7m0cytve/

which produces the expected result (centered image):

[image]

But `align=center` is deprecated.

When I change:

`<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0;" class="logo">`

to

`<td valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0; text-align:center" class="logo">`

the logo is no longer centered:

[image]

How do I remove `align=center` and get my logo to stay centered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `margin: 0 auto;` on your image then its centered without alignment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>A Responsive Email Template</title>
  <!--

    An email present from your friends at Litmus (@litmusapp)

    Email is surprisingly hard. While this has been thoroughly tested, your mileage may vary.
    It's highly recommended that you test using a service like Litmus (http://litmus.com) and your own devices.

    Enjoy!

 -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <style type="text/css">
    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body,
    table,
    td,
    a {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
    table,
    td {
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
    img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }

    body {
      height: 100% !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: inherit !important;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      font-weight: inherit !important;
      line-height: inherit !important;
    }

    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {

      /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
      .wrapper {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }

      /* ADJUSTS LAYOUT OF LOGO IMAGE */
      .logo img {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
      }

      /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
      }

      .img-max {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
      }

      /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
      .responsive-table {
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */
      .padding {
        padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
      }

      .padding-meta {
        padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .padding-copy {
        padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .no-padding {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      .section-padding {
        padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px !important;
      }

      /* ADJUST BUTTONS ON MOBILE */
      .mobile-button-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100% !important;
      }

      .mobile-button {
        padding: 15px !important;
        border: 0 !important;
        font-size: 16px !important;
        display: block !important;
      }

    }

    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] {
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">

  <!-- HIDDEN PREHEADER TEXT -->
  <div class="litmus-builder-preview-text" style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">Entice the open with some amazing preheader text. Use a little mystery and get those subscribers to read through...&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</div>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
            <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 500px;" class="wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0;" class="logo">
              <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img alt="Logo" src="https://www.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-samples/flooop.png" width="100" height="100" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px;" border="0">
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
            <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 500px;" class="responsive-table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- COPY -->
              <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 32px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; padding-top: 30px;" class="padding-copy">Your order is on its way!</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius,
                    leo a ullamcorper feugiat, ante purus sodales justo, a faucibus libero lacus a est. Aenean at mollis ipsum.</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 15px;" class="padding">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
            <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 500px;" class="responsive-table">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px 0 0 0; border-top: 1px dashed #aaaaaa;">
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
              <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="mobile-wrapper">
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">Purchased Item (1)</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="right">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">$XX.XX</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
              <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" style="padding: 0;" class="mobile-wrapper">
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">Shipping + Handling</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="right">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">$X.XX</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
              <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" style="padding: 0;" class="mobile-wrapper">
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">Sales Tax</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="right">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px;">$X.XX</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px 0 0px 0; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaaaaa;">
              <!-- TWO COLUMNS -->
              <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="mobile-wrapper">
                    <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="left">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">Total</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" style="width: 47%;" align="right">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #7ca230; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">$XX.XX</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
            <![endif]-->
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 500px;" class="responsive-table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- COPY -->
                    <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #aaaaaa; font-style: italic;" class="padding-copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                          adipiscing elit. Sed varius, leo a ullamcorper feugiat, ante purus sodales justo, a faucibus libero lacus a est. Aenean at mollis ipsum.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 15px;">
        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <!-- COPY -->
                  <td align="center" style="font-size: 32px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; padding-top: 30px;" class="padding-copy">How did we do?</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius,
                    leo a ullamcorper feugiat, ante purus sodales justo, a faucibus libero lacus a est. Aenean at mollis ipsum.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->
                    <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="padding-top: 25px;" class="padding">
                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#256F9C"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; padding: 15px 25px; border: 1px solid #256F9C; display: inline-block;"
                                  class="mobile-button">Let Us Know</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
            <![endif]-->
        <!-- UNSUBSCRIBE COPY -->
        <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="max-width: 500px;" class="responsive-table">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#666666;">
              1234 Main Street, Anywhere, MA 01234, USA
              <br>
              <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">Unsubscribe</a>
              <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #444444;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
              <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">View this email in your browser</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Because in this position we don't use flex, I Hate when front-end developers get addicted to use FLEX everywhere with no reason.!
plus flex is not supported in every single browser but margin does.

Comment: If I take out align=center there's still an alignment issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ts5p8zy2/

Comment: @Mary its becaz you need to add `margin: 0 auto;` to your img tag.
You can check my snippet thats the answer.!

Comment: My mistake but even with that code, the alignment doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/0hxgb8dr/

Comment: @Mary
Use this code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/14stmnLk/

Comment: @sm10 the fiddle works but if I change <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"> to <td bgcolor="#ffffff"> it doesn't work anymore and the main point is to remove the deprecated align="center"

Comment: @Mary here it is:  https://jsfiddle.net/6orha58z/
no alignment anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
margin: auto
```

will work